# c++ How to keep functions from being called on load inventoryGrid_CellValueChanged

Tags: winforms, datagridview, c++-cli

When I call the LoadItems() function, the event below is also triggered.

```
void InventoryList::LoadItems()
{
    string s = "select * from pos_db.items;";
    String^ cmdString = gcnew String(s.c_str());

    String^ conString = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader^ myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase->Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
        while(myReader->Read())
        {
            inventoryGrid->Rows->Add();
            DataGridViewRow^ row = inventoryGrid->Rows[inventoryGrid->RowCount - 1];
            row->Cells["alu"]->Value = myReader->GetString(0);
            row->Cells["upc"]->Value = myReader->GetString(1);
            row->Cells["vendor"]->Value = myReader->GetString(2);
            row->Cells["sku"]->Value = myReader->GetString(3);
            row->Cells["description"]->Value = myReader->GetString(4);
            row->Cells["size"]->Value = myReader->GetString(5);
            row->Cells["color"]->Value = myReader->GetString(6);
            row->Cells["price"]->Value = myReader->GetString(7);
            row->Cells["cost"]->Value = myReader->GetString(8);
            row->Cells["quantity"]->Value = myReader->GetString(9);
        }
        conDataBase->Close();
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
    }
}

private: System::Void inventoryGrid_CellValueChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellEventArgs^  e)
{
    if (inventoryGrid->Visible)
    {
        UpdateItem(e->RowIndex, inventoryGrid->Columns[e->ColumnIndex]->Name, (String^)inventoryGrid->Rows[e->RowIndex]->Cells[e->ColumnIndex]->Value);
    }
}
```

The inventoryGrid->Visible keeps the UpdateItem() function from being called when it initially loads, however when I search for an item it calls the LoadItems() function again which triggers the event again.  The trouble is that when it is called during a search, the DataGridView is visible and the UpdateItem() function is called.  How can I keep this from happening without having to see the DataGridView flicker quickly?

Comment: Which GUI framework in particular? Tag your question appropriately please (quickly), to avoid downvotes!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The event args is in the WinForms namespace.

Comment: @DavidYaw There was a number of improvements on this question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your searching code, so I'm not sure why searching requires you to call LoadItems again. Also, you haven't shown your code to UpdateItem, so we don't know what's going on in there.

That said, I'd consider adding a call to [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) & [`ResumeLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx). Do the suspend, then make all your modifications to the grid, then call resume.

Comment: The searching code has logic that doesn't add anything that would help. Basically it only calls the LoadItems() function.   I'll give that a shot though.